# Uniqueness of dimension in the infinite-dimensional case.

Tags: linear-algebra, transfinite-induction

Say $V$ is a vector space over some field.

> > **Lemma** Suppose $A,B,C\subset V$, $A\cup B$ spans $V$ and $B\cup C$ is independent. For  every $c\in C$ there exists $a\in A$ such that if $A'=A\setminus\{a\}$ and $B'=B\cup\{c\}$ then $A'\cup  B'$ spans $V$.

(Write $c$ as a linear combination of elements of $A\cup B$ and note that some element of $A$ must appear with a non-zero coefficient, since $B\cup C$ is independent...)

> > **Cor** Suppose $A$ spans $V$ and $C$ is independent. If $A$ is finite then $|A|\ge|C|$.

Proof: Let $A_0=A$, $B_0=\emptyset$, $C_0=C$. Apply the lemma repeatedly, setting $A_{n+1}=A_n'$, $B_{n+1}=B_n'$, $C_{n+1}=C_n'=C_n\setminus \{c\}$. If $|A|<|C|$ then there exists $n$ so that $A_n=\emptyset$ and $C_n\ne\emptyset$; hence $B_n$ is a proper subset of the independent set $C$ and $B_n$ spans $V$, contradiction.

**Question:** Is there a way to get the Corollary from the Lemma if $A$ is infinite?

**"My work so far:"** The obvious transfinite recursion. The problem is if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal: I can't imagine what' $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$ could be other than $\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}A_\beta$ and $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}B_\beta$, but in that case I see no reason that $A_\alpha\cup B_\alpha$ should span $V$.

The reason I suspect I may just be missing something is that in *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* Halmos comments that he tends to give proofs that can be generalized to the infinite-dimensional case.

**Edit:** It seems likely the answer is no, since nobody's come up with a yes. This raises the question "ok, how *do* you prove the corollary for infinite $A$?" In fact there's a very simple proof of the corollary for infinite $A$ on [Wikipedia;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) see the Answer below for a paraphrase.

For anyone missing the point:

**Exercise.** (i) Show that "maximal independent set" is equivalent to  "minimal spanning set". (ii) Explain why nonetheless the first phrase always comes up in a proof that every vector space has a basis, never the second..

Comment: I believe you want to do this with Zorn's lemma, instead of transfinite induction. If you want clarification I can write a complete answer.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Please do write that complete answer! The problem with Zorn's lemma is the same, as far as I can see: The intersection of a (decreasing) chain of spanning sets need not be a spanning set. (Hence part (ii) of the exercise...)

Comment: I'll admit that I underestimated the difficulty here. Do you know an example of a decreasing chain of spanning sets of which the intersection is not a spanning set?

Comment: Nevermind, I found one myself: $A_n:=\{1/k:k>n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think that the question exactly as it is stated would be a definite "no". You an't get the infinite-dimensional case *from the lemma*. That lemma will not get you past a limit ordinal as you've noticed. Of course, that doesn't mean there aren't other ways to handle it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair OK, then how do you do it? This is bugging me, because it's something I always thought was clear,  but I'm totally stuck on actually doing it...

Comment: @PaulSinclair Never mind. It's actually just as simple as I thought it "should" be - I feel silly not having come up with it myself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely the answer is no, since nobody's come up with a yes. This raises the question "ok, how *do* you prove the corollary for infinite $A$?" In fact there's a very simple proof of the corollary for infinite $A$ on [Wikipedia;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces). Here's the same proof, in a version that seems somewhat cleaner to me:

Suppose $A$  is infinite. Since any independent set is contained in a maximal independent set, wlog $C$ is actually a basis. For $c\in C$ let $\pi_c$ be the corresponding coordinate functional, so that $$x=\sum_{c\in C}\pi_c(x)c$$for every $x\in V$.

Let $S(x)$ be the support of $x\in V$: $$S(x)=\{c\in C:\pi_c(x)\ne0\}.$$Since $A$ spans $V$ it's clear that $$S(x)\subset S(A):=\bigcup_{a\in A}S(a)$$for every $x\in V$. We certainly have $$S(c)=\{c\}\quad(c\in C),$$ so $$C\subset S(A).$$And since $A$ is infinite and each $S(a)$ is finite it follows that $$|S(A)|\le|A|.$$

I feel so silly not having come up with that on my own.